# Backbone undefined error

Tags: backbone.js

I just started using Backbone but I cant go on because there is an error that `Backbone is not defined`. I included jQuery, Underscore and Backbone java script files, all paths are valid, but referencing `Backbone.Model.extend` gives me this error. Typing `Backbone` in Firefox console gives the same. What may be wrong?

```
<script src="{{ asset('libs/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('libs/underscore/underscore-min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('libs/backbone/backbone-min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        var System = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {
                shell: null,
                user: null
            },
            initialize: function () {
                this.set({'shell': new Shell()});
                this.set({'user': new User()});
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: We can't tell you if you don't post your code.

Comment: @Morslamina just updated

Comment: Use your console to confirm that the scripts are actually loaded.  You're looking for a successful `GET *path to backbone*`.

Comment: The path to `backbone-min.js` is wrong. Inspect the `script` tag and check exactly which path is being produced.

Comment: any console errors ? What versions of underscore & backbone are you trying to load ?

Comment: how do you know that all the paths are valid? can you actually see the valid requests in your firefox?

Comment: What are you using to set the paths? Not sure what the assets method is doing, that looks like handlebars templates, which would could cause a problem if the template is loaded after the page is originally loaded.